# RequireJS Conditional Loading Module in a synchronous way

Tags: javascript, requirejs, require, amd, js-amd

I have a module ModuleABC which loads modulea or moduleb depending on a flag, and after those module are loaded, calls init on the module method.

```
ModuleABC.js
define(['aa'],function(aa){
    var data;
    load = function(){
        if(data.IsAdmin){
            require(['moduleA'],function(modulea){
                modulea.init(data);
            });
        }
        else if
        {
            require(['moduleB'],function(moduleb){
                moduleb.init(data);
            });
        }
    }
    return initialize{
       load();
    }
})
```

Another Module requires the ModuleABC, but By the time i reach moduleabc.load(), i will not have my modulea or moduleb init method called.

```
Another Module dependent on ModuleABC
require(['ModuleABC'],function(moduleabc){
    moduleabc.load();
    By the time i reach here, i will not have my modulea or moduleb init method called.
    How do I achieve this?
});
```

Comment: Why not load everything you MIGHT need and only `init` the one you DO need?

Comment: The would be inefficient. The reason i'm conditionally loading module is to load only what's required and don't load unnecessary module.

Comment: Are you making an HTTP request for ever individual file?

Comment: I'm not doing that. Requirejs is doing internally I guess.

Comment: If they're all bundled together, then the dependency is only a _reference_ to that module. Unless simply requiring a module runs a bunch of code (and it shouldn't), loading a module and not initializing isn't going to be a material penalty.

Comment: If you load both modules up-front (as Mathletics suggests) you can achieve what you're trying to do synchronously.  Otherwise, you need to use some sort of async control flow to know when `load` has completed. Also as Mathletics says, the optimisation gained by not loading up-front is negligible if you've bundled you're code (which you should do in production).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the `load` function needs to be asynchronous.  Also, some of your JavaScript isn't valid, so I've corrected it:

**ModuleABC.js**

```
define(['aa'], function (aa) {
    var data;
    function load(cb) {
        var module = data.IsAdmin ? 'moduleA' : 'moduleB';
        require([module], function (module) {
            module.init(data);
            cb();
        });
    }
    return {
       initialise: load
    };
});
```

**AnotherModule.js**

```
require(['ModuleABC'], function (moduleabc) {
    moduleabc.load(function () {
        // By this point, either `moduleA` or `moduleB` will have been loaded and initialised
    });
});
```